# Call function anytime a link is moused over on an arbitrary page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

I apologize for the possibly naive nature of this question but I am not a web developer by day.

Is it possible to write a script such that, for any arbitrary web page, a function that I have written will be called if a URL is moused over? I was initially thinking that I could use document.links to assemble an array of all of the hrefs in a document and add an onmouseover event attribute to each of them but, unless I'm mistaken, that would overwrite any existing onmouseover attributes already present in the page. Not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if by arbitrary web page you mean any pages on any domains or any pages of your own domain, but for the latter you could put something like the following in your pages:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'a', function () {
        console.log(this, 'hovered');
    });
});
```

If you mean any page your browse to on the net, then you will have to write a browser extension for the browser your are using. For Chrome have a look at [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

Comment: Thanks, I actually am working on a browser extension as a means to learn web development, given that I only have a background in traditional desktop development — I appreciate the resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting everything with the `a` tag and inject an `onmouseover`.

```
window.onload = function(){
for(m=0;m<document.getElementsByTagName('a');m++){
  if(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[m].className == 'someclass'){
     document.getElementsByTagName('a')[m].onmouseover = function(){
        Your Code
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information — I'm using a variation of this approach using eventListeners and it seems to be working quite well. Thanks a lot for the information.